# Make call remotely from one phone through bluetooth using other phone?

Tags: bluetooth, calls, lineageos, 7.1-nougat, remote-access

I have two mobile phones:

- Samsung Galaxy S3 i9305 with SIM card
- Samsung Galaxy Note 3 N9005

I would like to

1. connect them with Bluetooth,
2. start my phone calls from Samsung Galaxy Note 3 remotely through Bluetooth,
3. the voice should go through Bluetooth to Samsung Galaxy S3, using its SIM card to make the phone call.

There is a remote Bluetooth sim solution named rSAP (Bluetooth Remote SIM Access Profile), which is used to remotely connect to car mobile.

http://www.android-rsap.com/bluetooth-sim-access-profile.html

But the developer of the app said, it will not work for the task I need:

> I don't think you will find a solution for your use case. It may be
>   possible to do it by using the "Handsfree" Bluetooth profile but I
>   doubt that the Android programming interfaces make a Handsfree client
>   possible. You will most probably have to create your own Android
>   firmware, e.g. based on LineageOS.

Is this possible to solve in some other way?

Comment: I'm not sure how, but i know it's possible because you can turn off sim card access in Bluetooth settings, So hypothetically you can use your Bluetooth as a remote sim card on the other device ! .... Their should be some sort of app out that will utilise this feature !

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a Hands free kit ( considering Bluetooth only reaches around 10m )

Comment: Why do you want to do this ? ...    If you explained the exact purpose for this, you will be more likely to get a concise answer !........      For example,   If you wanted to receive calls to your S3 on your S4, You'd set up a forwarding number and an immediate ring out time.  ....  If you wanted to make calls as your S3 number, you can use an application on the store called DingTone and set up your ID with a confirmation code on the S3....   If you wanted to do this because you have the wrong sim card ( micro, nano, etc )  Just cut or place the card exactly on the terminals ! cut corner up !

Comment: DingTone starts calls locally, not on my other phone through Bluetooth. No DingTone is not good for me.

Comment: You can WiFi Hotspot from your S3 to your S4 and make an internet call using your S3 Number in Dingtone .. It's a sort of work around for what you want !

Comment: It's just costly ! ... You could also set a Forwarding number on your S3 to your Dingtone number, And the you can ultimately call from your S3 number and receive calls via forwarding to your dingtone number... If you get me..... IT COSTS MONEY TO USE DINGTONE IN THIS MANNER !... But compared to buying credit or paying for plan rates ... It works out cheaper

Comment: Sorry, but none of your solutions match my described awaited solution.